# How do we extend CSLA.NET if we wanted to have our own business objects using c#

Tags: c#, csla

can we create our own platform/objects and interact it with CSLA.NET, is this possible or not? Can somebody out there who has more experience in CSLA.NET can help or advice. Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you want to achieve with your platform/objects?  This will allow much more detailed answers regarding how CSLA might or might not be applicable to your situation.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at Expert 2008 Business Objects and review your question.

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is: Your platform/objects will need CSLA?

First you need know what is csla and how you can use it?

CSLA is a framework to develop business objects, the framework provide a easy way to implement your business and validation rules, providing authorization checker in the object life cycle.

Csla implements a proxy (dataportal) to use your objects from web and windows application without any change. The csla objects can be easily bind to controls full functionality of error check. The nice work done in csla let you split your application follow a MDA and let for example the data access work to linq to sql.

So you must search in the functionality that you expect have your plataform/objects, if your object not will work with the business logic (very rare but posible), you could let that work to csla, if your object will do it doest not have any sense duplicate the functionality.

For more information about csla you can go to the owner web site at: http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Info.aspx.